# how I can load the minimum possible services to optimize the maximum performance of the system: executed at level 4?

Tags: boot

i have ubuntu 14.04 on virtual box, what services I can choose to be weighed in the next OS boot

Comment: note that the VM will always be slower than bare metal installations on a desktop virtualization platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start seeing what you can live without, are you **sure** that your "performance" is affected by "services"?  Have you monitored your system under load, identified bottlenecks, etc?

You can find the "services" started by the system with

```
sudo service --status-all
```

then look in `/etc/init/servicename.conf` and/or `/etc/init.d/servicename` to see how the service start up. Preventing service startup *could* be as simple as changing `start=1` to `start=0` in `/etc/default/servicename`. Not all services are this easy. **DO THE RESEARCH**

Another way to find "services" is via:

```
sudo lsof -i
```

and look for "`LISTEN`", and read `man lsof`.

Be sure you understand what a service does, and which other services on your system depend on it, before you make changes.

Most importantly (why is this always at the end?), Keep track of what changes you make, and try to make your changes reversible. For example, instead of

```
sudo rm /etc/service.conf
```

which deletes the file, do

```
sudo mv /etc/service.conf /etc/service.conf.DISABLED
```

which keeps the file, but, since it is no longer called `/etc/service.conf`, it not used by the example service.